# sketchup c++ api reading skp file

Tags: sketchup

I'd like to open a sketchup model in c++. I downloaded the sdk, compiled the example, however, when I try to run it, it doesn't read any face, model name, nothing. Could someone help me with?

```
SUInitialize();
// Load the model from a file
SUModelRef model = SU_INVALID;
SUResult res = SUModelCreateFromFile(&model, "model.skp");
if (res != SU_ERROR_NONE)
{
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
// Get the entity container of the model.
SUEntitiesRef entities = SU_INVALID;
SUModelGetEntities(model, &entities);

size_t faceCount = 0;
SUEntitiesGetNumFaces(entities, &faceCount);

// faceCount = 0..., why???!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the number of faces only in the root of the model, not those inside any component or group. Does model.skp have free faces? (i.e. not inside a component)